# Multiple beacons didRangeBeacons delegate call returning just one beacon at a time

Tags: ios

I am working with iBeacons. I have multiple beacons, each beacon having the same UUID, major, but different minor values. Both the devices are ranged but they are not received together, the 
- locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion: delegate callback "beacons" array contains only 1 beacon at a time.

I got to know that using multiple regions will have callback separately

This is how code for monitoring and ranging beacons

```
// Initialize and monitor regions
for (NSString *serviceUUID in _serviceUUIDs) {
  // Initialize region
  NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:serviceUUID];
  CLBeaconRegion *appBeaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid major:major minor:minor identifier:identifier];
  // Specify notifications
  appBeaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
  appBeaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = YES;
  appBeaconRegion.notifyOnExit = YES;
  // Add to regions
  [_appBeaconRegions addObject:appBeaconRegion];
  // Begin monitoring region and ranging beacons
  [_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:appBeaconRegion];
  [_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:appBeaconRegion];
}
```

I want to have all the beacons which are in range within single callback

How do i use single region with different minor, identifier values for all the beacons

Any help appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may use `BeaconManagerDelegate`'s `didFindBeacon` callback to observe beacons nearby. This will get all beacons if they have the same UUID.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I wrote for this purpose:-

```
// in ApplicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions
    let beaconID = NSUUID(UUIDString: "ADBD15B8-9A2F-492F-BB26-C7C92E05CAD3")
            let regionIdentifier = "humra.ibeacons"
            let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: beaconID!, identifier: regionIdentifier)
            if locationManager.respondsToSelector("requestAlwaysAuthorization")
            {
                locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            }
            locationManager.delegate=self
            locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically=false
            locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(beaconRegion)
            locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {
            NSLog("didRangeBeacons");
            let message:String = ""

            if(beacons.count > 0) {
                let nearestBeacon:CLBeacon = beacons[0] as CLBeacon
                closestBeacon=nearestBeacon

            } else {
    //            message = "No beacons are nearby"
            }

            NSLog("%@", message)
            sendLocalNotificationWithMessage(message)
        }
```